# Can't disable the logs Spark eclipse scala

Tags: eclipse, scala, logging, apache-spark, log4j

I am trying to disable the spark logs in a scala code. I have tried everything I could find but the logs are still appearing.

This is what I have done:

I edited the `log4j.properties` file and changed the following line:

from `log4j.rootCategory = WARNING, console`
to  `log4j.rootCategory = ERROR, console`

I also used the spark context to set the level to error or off:

```
sc.setLogLevel("OFF")
```

or to error:

```
sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")
```

I also imported the `log4j.Level` and `log4jLogger`

and did:

```
var rootLogger = Logger.getRootLogger()
rootLogger.setLevel(Level.FATAL)
```

and the last attempt:

```
Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF)
Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.OFF)
Logger.getLogger("spark").setLevel(Level.OFF)
```

But I am still getting info and warnings in my log.

Any ideas? My Spark version is 2.0.0

Answer (score 6):

Add the following piece of code before creating the SparkContext

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import org.apache.log4j.Level

Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF)
Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.OFF)
```

Comment: it didn't turn them off either

Answer (score 0):

go to src/test/resources dir in your workspace and create the file/dir if it does not exist
inside the directory paste the following code:

## Change this to set Spark log level

log4j.logger.org.apache.spark=WARN

## Silence akka remoting

log4j.logger.Remoting=WARN

## Ignore messages below warning level from Jetty, because it's a bit verbose

log4j.logger.org.eclipse.jetty=WARN

After this restart your ide and run the code.

Comment: This answer doesn't differ from other and not working as well.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following piece of code before creating the SparkContext or Session builder.

1. As an import statement:

   `import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}`
2. After the main method:

   `Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)`

Comment: Please put your code in the code block.